# Date object converted in MySQL and String has one second offset

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, simpledateformat

I'm using hibernate and spring with AWS' Aurora

And
datasource: 
    url: jdbc:mysql://test-cluster.xxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/db_example?**useLegacyDatetimeCode=false**
to convert timezone

```
@RestController
public class TestDate {
    @Autowired
    DateEntityRepository dateEntityRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/v0/test")
    public String test() {
        DateEntity dateEntity = new DateEntity();
        Date date = new Date();

        dateEntity.setCreateTime(date);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
        simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        String dateString = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
        dateEntity.setDateString(dateString);

        dateEntityRepository.save(dateEntity);

        return "ok";
    }
}
```

However there seems to be one second difference the dateTime and string in Aurora
[image: MySQL database]
which is weird. Can it be resolved or explained? Thanks.

Comment: Could it be a rounding issue? Your `Date` has millisecond precision. `SimpleDateFormat` will discard milliseoncds since they are not in the format pattern. I don’t know what MySQL does — could it be rounding up instead?

Comment: Thanks. [MySQL seem to rounding up seconds](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html). Now I'm just not sure what hibernate do.

Comment: I would be very surprised if Hibernate doesn’t keep the full accuracy; mostly negatively surprised. I suppose testing it will not be too hard.

Comment: @Chiu Hibernate datatype manipulations are in the *Dialect classes: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/ MySQLDialect.java; MySQL57InnoDBDialect.java; MySQL57Dialect.java There are some comments about MySQL and fractional seconds: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQL57InnoDBDialect.java#L23-L34